# ¿Poner etiqueta th sólo al principio o en otras partes de una tabla HTML?

Tags: html, buenas-prácticas

Estoy construyendo una tabla de forma dinámica leyendo un conjunto de resultados de la base de datos.

Esa tabla tendría sub-secciones que yo he decidido identificar poniéndoles la etiqueta `th`.

Esta será la tabla.

```html
        <table class="tabla-adviento">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">SEMANA-DÍA</th>

                    <th>HOMILÍAS</th>

                    <th>LECTURAS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tr id="titulo-adviento">
                <th colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="false">SEMANA I (DOMINGOS)</i></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>I</b></td>

                <td>Domingo (Ciclo A)</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-a_semana-01_tiempo-adviento_dia-01-domingo">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Is</strong> 2, 1-5<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 121, 1-2. 4-9<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 1, 1-2. 3. 4 y 6<br>
                <strong>Rm</strong> 13, 11-14<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/mt-24_37-44" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 24, 37-44</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>I</b></td>

                <td>Domingo (Ciclo B)</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-b_semana-01_tiempo-adviento_dia-01-domingo">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Is</strong> 63, 16b-17. 19b; 64, 2-7<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 79, 2ac y 3b. 15-16.18-19<br>
                <strong>1 Co</strong> 1, 3-9<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/mc-13_33-37" target="_blank"><strong>Mc</strong> 13, 33-37</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>I</b></td>

                <td>Domingo (Ciclo C)</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-c_semana-01_tiempo-adviento_dia-01-domingo">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Jer</strong> 33, 14-16<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 24, 4-5. 8-10. 14<br>
                <strong>1 Tes</strong> 3, 12—4, 2<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/lc-21_25-28-y-34-36" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 21, 25-28. 34-36</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="subtitulo-adviento">
                <th colspan="4">Ferias Semana I</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>I</b></td>

                <td>Lunes</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-01_tiempo-adviento_dia-02-lunes">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Is</strong> 2, 1-5<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 121, 1-4. 6-9<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/mt-08_05-11" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 8, 5-11</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>I</b></td>

                <td>Martes</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-01_tiempo-adviento_dia-03-martes">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Is</strong> 11, 1-10<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 71, 1-2. 7-8. 12-13. 17<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/lc-10_21-24" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 10, 21-24</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>I</b></td>

                <td>Miércoles</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-01_tiempo-adviento_dia-04-miercoles">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Is</strong> 25, 6-10a<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 22, 1-3a. 3b-4. 5. 6<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/mt-15_29-37" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 15, 29-37</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>I</b></td>

                <td>Jueves</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-01_tiempo-adviento_dia-05-jueves">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Is</strong> 26, 1-6<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 117, 1. 8-9. 19-21. 25-27<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/mt-07_21-y-24-27" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 7, 21. 24-27</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>I</b></td>

                <td>Viernes</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-01_tiempo-adviento_dia-06-viernes">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Is</strong> 29, 17-24<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 26, 1.4 .7-8<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/mt-09_27-31" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 9, 27-31</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>I</b></td>

                <td>Sábado</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-01_tiempo-adviento_dia-07-sabado">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Is</strong> 30, 19-21. 23-26<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 146, 1-2. 3-4. 5-6<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/mt-09_35-y-10_01-y-06-08" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 9, 35–10, 01. 06-08</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="titulo-adviento">
                <th colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="false">SEMANA II (DOMINGOS)</i></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>II</b></td>

                <td>Domingo (Ciclo A)</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-a_semana-02_tiempo-adviento_dia-01-domingo">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Is</strong> 11, 1-10<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 71, 1-2. 7-8. 12-13. 17<br>
                <strong>Rm</strong> 15, 4-9<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/mt-03_01-12" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 3, 1-12</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>II</b></td>

                <td>Domingo (Ciclo B)</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-b_semana-02_tiempo-adviento_dia-01-domingo">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Is</strong> 40, 1-5. 9-11<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 84, 9abc y 10. 11-12. 13-14<br>
                <strong>2 Pe</strong> 3, 8-14<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/mc-01_01-08" target="_blank"><strong>Mc</strong> 1, 1-8</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>II</b></td>

                <td>Domingo (Ciclo C)</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-c_semana-02_tiempo-adviento_dia-01-domingo">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Bar</strong> 5, 1-9<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 125, 1-6<br>
                <strong>Flp</strong> 1, 4-6. 8-11<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/lc-03_01-06" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 3, 1-6</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="subtitulo-adviento">
                <th colspan="4">Ferias Semana II</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>II</b></td>

                <td>Lunes</td>

                <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-02_tiempo-adviento_dia-02-lunes">Homilías</a></td>

                <td><span class="mediana"><strong>Is</strong> 35, 1-10<br>
                <strong>Sal</strong> 84, 9abc y 10. 11-12. 13-14<br>
                <a href="http://www.deiverbum.org/lc-05_17-26" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 5, 17-26</a><br></span></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Yo identificado las sub-secciones así por ejemplo:

```
       <tr id="titulo-adviento">
            <th colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="false">SEMANA I (DOMINGOS)</i></th>
        </tr>
```

Esta es otra:

```
        <tr id="subtitulo-adviento">
            <th colspan="4">Ferias Semana I</th>
        </tr>
```

**Mi duda es sobre si el uso de `th` en partes que no son el encabezado de la tabla podría considerarse una mala práctica. Si así fuese, ¿habría otra forma de expresar sub-secciones en una tabla?**

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

Para agrupar las filas de las secciones de tu tabla usa `<tbody>` y `<th>` para señalar las celdas que son encabezados de sección.

## Explicación

De acuerdo a [HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TH), `<th>` es para especificar una celda de encabezado y `<td>` para especificar una celda de datos, por otro lado, para [agrupar filas](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#rowgroups)  se puede usar ,`<thead>` cuando se trata agrupar filas del encabezado de tabla, `<tfoot>`cuando se trata de agrupar filas del pie de tabla y `<tbody>` para agrupar las filas del cuerpo de la tabla.